# Curved text with XeLaTeX and Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

Trying to get curved text to work, using tikz, curve text works but I am unable to set an outline or color to the text. I am using XeLaTeX because of fontspec and being able to use my own custom fonts.

Below is what I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0.2pt}%

\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=/path/to/fonts/]{"HelveticaLTStd-Roman.ttf"}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (Start) at (-3,0) {};
  \node (End) at (3,0) {};
  \draw [decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={SOME LONG TEXT}}] (Start) to [bend right=45] (End);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

The end goal is to get something like [image: this] with a outline around each character.

Comment: Why load packages & libraries twice? Why load `color`?

Comment: @cfr Those are probably left over from a bunch of testing I've been doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to change text color you can add `text color=...` after `text={...}` command.
For setting an outline to your text you can use and edit the code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{0.2pt}%

\setmainfont[ExternalLocation=/path/to/fonts/]{"HelveticaLTStd-Roman.ttf"}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mycontour#1{\textcolor{white}{\contour{blue}{#1}}}
  \node (Start) at (-3,0) {};
  \node (End) at (3,0) {};
  \draw [decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={SOME LONG TEXT},text effects along path,text effects/.cd, characters={character command=\mycontour, font=\tiny}}] (Start) to [bend right=45] (End);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you test this?! I'm assuming not ... Or else you lost something in transition. Why add 2 incompatible decorations? Why load packages twice? Why load `color`?

Comment: I test it and it works. I quickly modify the question code and I have not noticed the repetition in preample. Sorry!

Comment: I meant that you're missing the end of the document. You have unclosed environments - including `document`.

Comment: @josky I'm hoping to have something like https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgqza81dyf3zl92/Screenshot%202016-12-05%2021.16.59.png?dl=0 but with the code you gave me, and using a black text with blue outline I get https://www.dropbox.com/s/t14ca9gx97zvvz1/Screenshot%202016-12-05%2021.18.18.png?dl=0

Comment: You can remove everything after text={...} in \draw options command (inside the [...]). You lost the contour effect, but it works and it's similar to what you want.